# Ideas for Pareto-Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

tomorrow i have to present an exercise which is about estimating the MLE of a Pareto-Distribution. I wanted to add a funny background story to make my presentation a little bit more interesting. Could you provide me some funny ideas about things that could be described by a pareto-distribution?

Comment: Incomes, for instance, here https://economics.mit.edu/files/10517 for a broader description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the Pareto 80/20 law.

E.g. $20\%$ of all people receive $80\%$ of all income.

This phenomenon can be seen in the Pareto distribution when $\alpha$ is set to a particular value.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle#Mathematical_notes

Answer (score 2):

I agree with George!

You might find some of these examples interesting: [link](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-most-surprising-real-life-examples-of-the-Pareto-Principle-the-so-called-%E2%80%9C80-20-rule%E2%80%9D)

Also baseball: 15% of baseball players lead to 85% of wins (in 2009) [link](https://www.beyondtheboxscore.com/2010/6/4/1501048/applying-the-parento-principle-80)

The principle is often used to help determine priorities. E.g., [in fashion](https://www.rajasfashions.com/the-8020-rule/) or [sales](https://pureb2b.com/blog/sales-8020-rule-take-advantage/)